# "Wrong wmode value" when using Starling with an AVD

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, android-emulator, starling-framework

I am currently using FlashDevelop set up with the Flex/AIR SDK and Starling. I have used the AIR for Android AS3 template and have successfully compiled test applications without initializing Starling perfectly fine. These applications run fine on my Android Virtual Device.
But as soon as I initialize a Starling instance, the error "This application is not properly embedded (wrong wmode value)" shows up in a red bar in the middle of the screen. I've looked through the Starling forums and have set direct, but I am still getting the error. I have also set -swf-version=15, and I still get the error.
What's really weird, is that when I compile with the FlashPlayer 11, everything works perfectly fine. Only when I compile and install on the AVD does the error show up. Trace output still appears fine in logcat, my debugger, before the _starling.start() statement.

This person seems to be having similar problems if my explanation wasn't clear: http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/wmode-issue-with-rendering-mode-direct

And yes, I have set my AVD to use GPU acceleration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You've probably sorted this out by now, but just in case anyone else comes across this thread...

Go in to you *-app.xml file and search for `<!--<renderMode></renderMode>-->` untag it and add direct between the tags so it looks like `<renderMode>direct</renderMode>`