# Overlay starling flash object with transparent html object

Tags: html, css, flash, starling-framework

I know ([I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040887/div-z-index-issue-with-flash-movie)) that flash objects are generally displayed on top of everything else, unless the `wmode` is `window`, `opaque` or `transparent`.

But the framework [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/) seems to require `direct` as the `wmode`, so this isn't an option.

I've tried putting the flash object inside an iframe, but this didn't work either.

Do you know how to:

1. modify Starling to work with a `wmode` different than `direct`
2. display html elements above flash objects that have the `wmode` `direct`

**Edit**
Transparent html objects appear to behave different than non-transparent ones.
The optimal solution should work for elements with `opaque` < 1 as well ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B6xg5/))

Answer (score 0):

I dont know anything about starling.

But you could do something with css and z-index. If for example:

```
.myflash {position:relative; z-index:1}
.somethingelse {z-index:2;}
```

The object with z-index 2 would apear over the top of the flash.

Comment: Thanks, this works for normal html objects. But if they are partly transparent (`opaque` < 1) they still hide behind the flash object (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B6xg5/). Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: For me, in the fiddle its not hiding, its over the top of the flash...  otherwise you would not be able to see it at all?

Comment: do you see both overlays? The right one has an opacity of 0.9 and all I can see of it is the little part that's above the flash object

Comment: I see both. What browser are you using?

Comment: Works in chrome. But in firefox i only see the top. In IE i see only the tops of bot. But i think i might be able to fix. Give me a min...

Comment: You're right. It works fine in chrome, safari & IE hide both. Opera displays both, but the transparent one isn't transparent - it's just not so dark. I was working with firefox. Thank you for your help, take your time!

Comment: Well opera does not really like transparency. You could use a transparent png as the background to solve that. Regarding the browser issue, this is down to as you say the wmode. it needs to be 'opaque' or 'transparent' - can you not just add the parameters when you embed the flash?

Comment: Unfortunately not, Starling does not work with a different `wmode` than `direct` (as far as I know). Thanks anyway - I'll accept you answer if no one else comes up with a solution for all browsers during the next few days.

Comment: I found a related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112634/wrong-wmode-value-when-using-starling-with-an-avd

Comment: You may be able to do what he says "Go in to you *-app.xml file and search for <!--<renderMode></renderMode>--> untag it and add transparent between the tags so it looks like <renderMode>transparent</renderMode>

Comment: If that is not relevant. What i would do is downoad the entire sites files, create a site in dreamweaver or simalar program and search the entire site for the word 'direct' - it has to be in there somewhere. Then test changing them to 'transparent' or 'opaque'